# Afetr release ios build, It is lagging a lot in react native ts

Tags: react-native, testflight

After generating release ios build,It is working fine in ios simulator but lagging a lot in real devices ex:- Iphone 14Pro and 14Pro Max. I have used the realse mode from Schema and followed all the essentials guildlines.

I am using
"react-native": "0.71.6",
"Xcode Version":Version 14.3.1 (14E300c)